# Why does jquery not return the very last entry of DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

**My expected Goal:**

I am trying to select the very last node of a DOM Element which is covered by following regex:

```
/(\[{3})[A-Z]+(\]{3})(\[{3})([0-9]{1,3})(\.*)([0-9]*)(\]{3})/g;
```

This regex will cover Strings like `[[[WIDTHCHANGE]]][[[250]]]` or `[[[HEIGHTCHANGE]]][[[250]]]`. So Strings with 3 times `[` and `]` and text in between and another 3 times `[` and `]` and a number in between.

**My Structure:**

I have a Div Element which contains many span-elements and the very last span element contains this `[[[WIDTHCHANGE]]][[[250]]]`.

**My current status:**

And now I want to select only this span element which contains a text covered by the regex mentioned above. But JQuery selects the parent of the parent of the specific element.

Below is my JS-Search-Code:

```
var regex = /(\[{3})[A-Z]+(\]{3})(\[{3})([0-9]{1,3})(\.*)([0-9]*)(\]{3})/g;
var  ElementsToChange_ = $("span").filter(function () {
    return regex.test($(this).text()); 
}).last();
```

Is there anything I am missing or missunderstanding?

EDIT 1:

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bf089uo5/) Link!

Comment: Any fiddle available ?

Comment: @AdnanUmer provided ;)

Comment: Issue is with regex. `regex.test("Links [[[WIDTHCHANGE]]][[[250]]]")` gives  alternating `true` & `false` i.e. in first attempt that is `true` and in second that is `false`. However text remains the same. Strange behavior

Comment: jsFiddle links aren't necessary. What's necessary is to include all relevant information *directly* in the question. Looking at this page, there's still no way to know the issue without visiting another site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you select span you get ALL spans. Because the span has the text in it that matches, just happens it is nested with another span that has the text.

Now the solutions depend on what can be in the span, but in your cause you can probably just select spans that do not have spans in them.

```
$("span:not(:has(span))").filter(...)
```

if it can have other elements inside such as  `<span>xxxx<span>foo</span></span>` than it is a little more tricky. You would need to remove the children nodes and then read the text.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with Regular Expressions. Regular Expression defined by surrounding with `/` is showing unexpected behavior for two same things when reused.

[image: Strange Behavior of Regular Expressions]

There might be two possible workarounds for that

1. Use Inline Regular Expression [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bf089uo5/2/)

   ```
   var ElementsToChange_ = $("span").filter(function () {
       return /(\[{3})[A-Z]+(\]{3})(\[{3})([0-9]{1,3})(\.*)([0-9]*)(\]{3})/g.test($(this).text());
   }).last();
   console.log(ElementsToChange_);
   ```
2. Create Regex by calling constructor `RegExp` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bf089uo5/1/)

   ```
   var regex = RegExp("(\\[{3})[A-Z]+(\\]{3})(\\[{3})([0-9]{1,3})(\\.*)([0-9]*)(\\]{3})");
   var ElementsToChange_ = $("span").filter(function () {
       return regex.test($(this).text()); 
   }).last();
   console.log(ElementsToChange_);
   ```

Comment: That issue isn't related to the regex literal syntax using `/`. It's because of the `g` modifier on the regex, which your `RegExp` constructor doesn't include. Drop the `g` from the literal, and it'll fix that issue, though it's only part of the OP's problem.